# Copy content from div element via button to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, clipboard.js

I am working on a simple program that takes input from user and performs arithmetic function on the input value and then displays result in div element via innerHTML. I have tried the ClipboardJS library with implementing data target in button to target div element content but it's not showing any result.

Can you help me, please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("copybutton").style.display = "none";

  $("#showbuttonid").click(function() {
    var a = $("input#inputvaluebox").val();
    var b = a * 10;
    var b = "Value is" + b;
    document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("copybutton").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("idofdiv").innerHTML = b;
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&display=swap');
.labelclass {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.inputvaluecss {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 42px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  width: 275px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.inputvaluecss:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #2EDC29;
  border: 1px solid #2EDC29;
}

.divclass {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <br>
  <label for="inputvaluebox" class="labelclass">Input Value</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputvaluebox" name="inputvaluename" class="inputvaluecss"><br><br>

  <input type="reset" id="resetbuttonid">
  <button type="button" id="showbuttonid">Show</button><br><br><br>

  <div id="idofdiv" class="divclass"></div><br>
  <button type="button" id="copybutton" data-clipboard-target="#idofdiv">Copy content!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your actual issue here? If I enter a 1 and click show, it shows `Value is10`. There is only a space character missing. You are not using the clipboard anywhere

Comment: Hi @yunzen I have added the data-clipboard-target in the button attribute also, added the library of clipboardJS to the program. It is not copying even after adding the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one more line of code. Just take a read in the official documentation: https://clipboardjs.com/#setup

```
  new ClipboardJS('#copybutton')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("copybutton").style.display = "none";

  $("#showbuttonid").click(function() {
    var a = $("input#inputvaluebox").val();
    var b = a * 10;
    var b = "Value is " + b;
    document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("copybutton").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("idofdiv").innerHTML = b;
  });
  
  new ClipboardJS('#copybutton')
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@600&display=swap');
.labelclass {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.inputvaluecss {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 42px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  width: 275px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.inputvaluecss:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #2EDC29;
  border: 1px solid #2EDC29;
}

.divclass {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <br>
  <label for="inputvaluebox" class="labelclass">Input Value</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputvaluebox" name="inputvaluename" class="inputvaluecss"><br><br>

  <input type="reset" id="resetbuttonid">
  <button type="button" id="showbuttonid">Show</button><br><br><br>

  <div id="idofdiv" class="divclass"></div><br>
  <button type="button" id="copybutton" data-clipboard-target="#idofdiv">Copy content!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working thanks a lot, but just one question here how it is possible that there is no ';' at the end of   new ClipboardJS('#copybutton')

Comment: https://dev.to/adriennemiller/semicolons-in-javascript-to-use-or-not-to-use-2nli

Comment: @inforedinn If this answer solves your issue, please accept it (check the tickmark to the left of the answer)

Comment: Yea it does @yunzen

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is trying to add math functions to string
In your case `a` is a string and `b` is a number 
So you try to convert `a` to number and `b` to string. That won't work
This worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("copybutton").style.display = "none";

  $("#showbuttonid").click(function() {
    var a = $("input#inputvaluebox").val();
    var c = parseInt(a)
    var b = c * 10;
    var d = "Value is" + b;
    document.getElementById("idofdiv").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("copybutton").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("idofdiv").innerHTML = d;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Shkelqim Maxharraj, the function is supposed to return value in div innerHTML and then copy it from there. Thanks for answer